# Can an Android text message set off an alarm?

Tags: sms, alarm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how be woken up by receiving a text message with an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/601/how-be-woken-up-by-receiving-a-text-message-with-an-android-phone)

Is there an Android feature that will allow my phone to set off an alarm when I receive a text message from a specific phone number? If not, is there an app that does this?

I want to turn text messages I receive from my employer into pages. So, whenever I receive a text message from a specific phone number, I want my phone to keep ringing until I hit a "snooze" or "done" button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Android Anti-Theft Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snuko.android&hl=en) and [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=en) both provide these functions, along with many other security apps available for Android. There is also an app called [SMS Alarm Pager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sil.sms.alarm&feature=search_result) which sounds like exactly what you need, but I cannot tell as the description is in another language :/

Answer (score 8):

[Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) can automate things like that -- and a lot more. It takes a while to acquaint oneself with it, and 5 bucks to buy (there's a 7day trial available as well) -- but it's well worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that try to duplicate pager functionality for specific phone numbers, such as SMS Alerter and Alarm: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/communication/sms-alerter-n-alarm-lite_cgudj.html

The documentation specifies that it provides an alarm snooze functionality, as well as some pager-specific functionality (quick respond/dismiss).

However, that particular app doesn't seem to work for everybody - there are some negative reviews out there.